# ScreenUpdating Office-js taskpane

Tags: excel, office-js

While developing a new taskpane addin we push a large two dementional object ot the excel workbook and format some rows based on another object.

While doing this the user can see his excel workbook flickering.

With the old com api there was a salution by turning off the screen updateing property.
[ScreenUpdating MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173689(v=office.11).aspx)

is there something like this in office-js for excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office-js doesn't have an API to turning off screen updating. The flickering you mentioned is probably the control going back-n-forth between the data update and control returning to the UI. During this update timeframe, the API allows user to interact with Excel UI such as button/mouse clicks, selection, etc. I do understand this can be bothersome.

We are adding some features to help speed-up the update itself such as by delaying the calculation. This will reduce the duration for which users see the update mode on and off.