# Long time of inserting HTML to content controller

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm currently developing Microsoft Office add-in on Word Online. I have large amount of content controllers (more than 100), and I have to replace in every content controller one stylled text to another in one action. For example

"**Document** blabla *nr 1*"  to "**Document** blabla *nr 2*"

Only numbers changes in this oparation. So my problem is that I'm using function contentController.insertHTML(styled html text) to achieve this result, but it takes a very long time for such large number of content controllers. For 100 content controller it takes about 1 min to change it all! **Has anybody got idea how can I do it much faster?**

Thank You for reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have had performance problems updating values in large tables.  See my post:  [Office.js Word Add-In: Performance Issue with Updating Values in Large Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910445/office-js-word-add-in-performance-issue-with-updating-values-in-large-tables).  There may be some helpful ideas there.  The easiest may be to reduce screen updating impact by scrolling to top or part of document so your content controls are not visible.

Comment: Thx for help!:)